# MySQL errorcode 1005 errno 105

Tags: mysql

I got error 1005 errno 105 when trying to create an 'attack_relationship' table. 
The 'attack_relationship' table has 2 foreign keys used as primary keys from the 'argument table: `attackedArgumentId` and `attackingArgumentId`.

It also references a composite foreign key from 'critical_question' table `(argumentId, critical_question.id)`.

The argumentId in the critical_question table references `attackedArgumentId` from the argument table.

If I were to delete the relationship between 'attack_relationship' to 'critical_question' the 'attack_relationship' table can be created without any error. The problem is I need `attackedArgumentId`, `attackingArgumentId` and `criticalQuestionId` as primary keys in attack_reltationship table.

Here is the detail of the error and the code:

**Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'argupedia.attack_relationship' (errno: 150)**

```
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `argupedia`.`attack_relationship` (
          `attackedArgumentId` BIGINT ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
          `attackingArgumentId` BIGINT ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
          `criticalQuestionId` INT NOT NULL,
          `userDefined` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
          INDEX `fk_attack_relationship_argument1_idx` (`attackedArgumentId` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_attack_relationship_argument2_idx` (`attackingArgumentId` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_attack_relationship_critical_question1_idx` (`attackedArgumentId` ASC, `criticalQuestionId` ASC),
          PRIMARY KEY (`attackedArgumentId`, `attackingArgumentId`, `criticalQuestionId`),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_attack_relationship_argument1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`attackedArgumentId`)
            REFERENCES `argupedia`.`argument` (`id`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_attack_relationship_argument2`
            FOREIGN KEY (`attackingArgumentId`)
            REFERENCES `argupedia`.`argument` (`id`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_attack_relationship_critical_question1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`criticalQuestionId` , `attackedArgumentId`)
            REFERENCES `argupedia`.`critical_question` (`id` , `argumentId`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

**SQL script execution finished: statements: 10 succeeded, 1 failed**

**Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch**

Answer (score 0):

Use `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` to find out  the exact reason why the constraints are failing